# Post variable undefined in Braintree transaction

Tags: php, swift, macos, swift3, braintree

I am setting up payment processing for my OSX desktop app in swift.  Since there is no SDK for OSX, I am using a Web View via the PHP SDK for Braintree. I want to pass some POST data so that the price of a product is coming dynamically from my App, but it seems to not be recognized and is underfined according to PHP errors.
I know how to send POST variable to a PHP script and have done it many times, but I have a feeling something might not be right with my swift code.  My PHP error is:  "Notice: Undefined variable: price"

**PayPal.swift**

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class PayPal: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var paypalWebView: WebView?

override func viewWillAppear() {

    self.view.window!.title = "Payment"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupPP()

}

func setupPP(){

    let request: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://")!

    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: request as URL)

    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "price=45"
    urlRequest.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {

            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")

        }

        let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")

    }

    task.resume()

    let requesting = NSURLRequest(url: request as URL)

    DispatchQueue.main.async(){
        self.paypalWebView?.mainFrame.load(requesting as URLRequest)
    }

}

}
```

**Braintree PHP Script**

```
if(isset($_POST["price"])){

$price = $_POST["price"];

}

<?php $tr_data = Braintree_TransparentRedirect::transactionData(
                array('redirectUrl' => "http://" ,
                'transaction' => array('amount' => $price, 'type' => 'sale'))) ?>
```

Also the Paypal View that is essentially a web view is being activated when a user clicks on a button via a segue.  I don't know if that would have anything to do with it or not?

Comment: What happens when you add `var_dump($_POST)` to your PHP code ?

Comment: I get array(0) { }.  I am not sure why it isn't coming through.

Comment: Most likely your switft code is not sending the POST (or any request at all) to your PHP code. You can maybe use Firebug/Web Developer browser plugins to track GET/POST requests to see if the data flows from Swift to PHP.

Comment: Its so weird because I have many other scripts doing very similar things.  I have no problem posting data for my register and login controllers but for some reason my price will not go through.

Comment: Does it matter that my view controller aka my web view is being initiated from another view controllers button via segue?

Comment: I an not sure. I know some PHP but no Swift whatsoever.

Comment: I got rid of my PHP error via : $amount    = (isset($_POST['amount'])    ? $_POST['amount']    : ''); but it still doesnt pass my poststring valuefrom my swift app

Comment: Right. You just added additional condition checking to not show an error in PHP (which is a good thing) but you are still not getting the POST value from your Swift code, which is a bigger issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it to work!

**Paypal.swift**

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class PayPal: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var paypalWebView: WebView?

override func viewWillAppear() {

    self.view.window!.title = "Payment"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupPP()

}


func setupPP(){

    let request: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://")!

    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: request as URL)

    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "amount=29.95"
    urlRequest.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {

            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")

        }

        let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")

    }

    paypalWebView?.mainFrame.load(urlRequest as URLRequest)

    task.resume()


}

}
```

**PHP Script**

```
<?php
            if (isset ($_POST['amount'])) {

                    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
            }

            $tr_data = Braintree_TransparentRedirect::transactionData(
                array('redirectUrl' => "http://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . ":" . $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] . parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH),

                'transaction' => array('amount' => $amount, 'type' => 'sale'))) 

?>
```